# the function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Alright, so I'm making a form validation everything is good in this JS, but now I'm facing a problem in the output, I am trying to display all the chosen data. So I used the action attribute and called the following function:

```
function funcs()
    {
    var favor = document.reg.favor[selectedIndex].value; //Select input
    var fname = document.reg.fname.value; // text input
    var lname = document.reg.lname.value; // text input
    var email = document.reg.email.value; // text input
    var pass = document.password.value; //text input
    for(i=0;i<document.reg.rad.length;i++)
        {
            if(document.reg.rad[i].checked == true)
            {
                var rad = document.reg.rad[i].value; // Radio input
            }
        }
    if(document.reg.bike.checked == true)
        {
            var bike =  document.reg.bike.value; //CheckBox input
        }
    if(document.reg.car.checked == true)
        {
            var car = document.reg.car.value; //CheckBox input
        }
    document.write('<head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="registrationtable.css"/></head><body>');
    document.write("<div class = 'team'>");
    document.write('<table>');
    document.write("<tr><td> שם  פרטי: </td><td>" + fname + "</td></tr> <tr><td> שם משפחה: " + lname + "</td></tr> <tr><td> אימייל: " + email + "</td></tr> <tr><td> סיסמא: " +pass +"</td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td> השחקן האהוב עליך הוא " + favor +"</td></tr>"); 
    document.write("</table>");
    document.write("</div></body>");
    }
```

Here's the form header:

```
<form name ="reg" action ="Javascript:funcs()" onsubmit ="return checkValidation()">
```

**I'd like to clear that all the other javascript code is working perfectly, it must be something with this function.**
When I'm pressing the send button, it won't do anything. Anyone knows whats the problem?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: ARe you sure checkValidation is returning true?

Comment: For one, you have no `checkValidation` function in your code snippets. can't return a value from a function which doesn't exist...

Comment: Marc B i'm assuming `checkValidation()` is "all the other javascript code that is working perfectly" And `funcs` is the function that is not. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder You're not wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected. One problem is this line:

```
var favor = document.reg.favor[selectedIndex].value;
```

It should be

```
var favor = document.reg.favor[document.reg.favor.selectedIndex].value;
```

And your second problem is this:

```
var pass = document.password.value;
```

Should be:

```
var pass = document.reg.password.value;
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x7SBy/1/

Finally, you should use Firefox and download Firebug. It is invaluable for debugging JS problems like this.

Edit: There are other problems with your JS that I won't get into in detail, but in general you don't want to use document.reg.password, because of issues like this. You should really use document.getElementById. FYI.

Answer (score 4):

You  <strike>[can't](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-action)</strike>  **shouldn't** have a javascript function in your `action` attribute, it needs to be a URI. You can just call the `funcs` `onsubmit` if validation succeeded.

As Aquinas has shown that calling a javascript function in the action attribute is in fact possible, it is advised that you not put js code in the action attribute.

Comment: "This attribute specifies a form processing agent. User agent behavior for a value other than an HTTP URI is undefined." I'm not saying you *should* do this. In fact, you shouldn't, but in IE 9, Chrome, and Firefox, the behavior is that it calls the function. What browser are you using where you see a different behavior?

Comment: @aquinas I'm using google chrome, so it means there not should be any problem.. it's problem with the code then?

Comment: Thanks aquinas, i have corrected the answer, i was attempting to do it without the `javascript:` prepended to the function.

Comment: @idish, Possibly. Why don't you create a new fiddle over at jsfiddle.net and paste your entire code. If I had to take a guess at your problem. I'd guess that selectedIndex isn't something you have actually defined before outside this function. 

So this line: var favor = document.reg.favor[selectedIndex].value; 

Should be more like: 

var favor = document.reg.favor[document.reg.favor.selectedIndex].value;

Comment: @aquinas I erased the favor and still im facing the same problem.(also the document.write with the favor printing)

Comment: look at your console in the web developer tools and see if you get any errors.

Comment: I tried to debug my code and I'm getting the following error what does it mean?: Problem at line 1 character 1: Unexpected ''.

<html>

Problem at line 1 character 1: Stopping, unable to continue. (0% scanned).

<html>

Comment: @idish, like I said, copy and paste ALL your code to jsfiddle.net

Comment: @idish, when I said "copy and paste ALL your code to jsfiddle.net" I meant **********ALL************ your code. Where is all your HTML?

Comment: idish, here you go it works for me after correcting a few syntax errors. http://jsfiddle.net/x7SBy/2/

Comment: Just a side note, in the real world this code would be considered outdated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to validate a form, then if valid call the `funcs` function to alter HTML on the page.

Maybe something like this:

```
<form name="reg" action="" onsubmit="checkValidation()">
```

Then a `checkValidation` function to pause form submission and if valid, call the `funcs` function:

```
function checkValidation(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (checkValidation()) {
        funcs();
    }
}
```

But if this is the case, your `funcs` function should not be writing `<head>` tags and such. Maybe you could just add HTML to the body instead of trying to lay a new HTML document into the DOM with javascript.

**Alternate solution**:

```
function checkValidation() {
   ... do your validation

   return true; // or false if invalid
}
```

Then use a real HTML page/resource in your action tag of the `form`.